# Xserver ubuntu password error?

Tags: password, xserver

I'm running my python script on aws using ubuntu(file upload by filezilla and using putty for connection), as my script is console application I have to run Xserver but right when I write the command to run Xsever which is:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm start
```

it said that

```
 [sudo] password for ubuntu:
```

And I don't know what is the password.

edit: version Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, codename: Jammy

Can anyone help?

Comment: You've provided no release (or product) details; where the installer usually (*most products*) provides the password; but without product & release details we cannot know what password is required. I'd suggest speaking to whomever installed or set it up.

Comment: @guiverc version Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, codename: Jammy

Comment: We also don't know what is your password.

Comment: did you get/set a password on AWS?

Comment: When installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (*you didn't specify if server or desktop was installed but on official Ubuntu ISOs*) the installer sets the password. Ask the person who installed it what password they set.